# Is increasing jest.setTimeout() a good practice?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a case where I am mocking an API Put request in the Jest file like this.

```
    ....
    ....
    const mockSocialPostUpdate = jest
      .spyOn(api, "put")
      .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
    
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockSocialPostUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        expect.objectContaining({ path: "/api/v1/social-posts/:id" }),
        { id: postContent.id },
        {
          id: postContent.id,
          text: updatedDelta
        }
      );
    });
```

I am not sure why but only in this test file I am getting

```
 Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

Now the only solution that works is by putting `jest.setTimeout(30000);` but I am not sure if it's the best practice. How can I investigate why am I getting a timeout error for this test. I am doing console.logs and the Put request is happening and I am reaching the `await WaitFor()` function

Comment: The answer would depend on the type of the test you're trying to perform. If it's an unit test - you should mock the API call, so you'll get the response immediately. And if it's an e2e test - 5 seconds might not be enough in some cases, so this would be your only option

Comment: yeah I am mocking as shown in the example

Comment: Probably you're mocking the implementation after the component have already called the actual implementation. Try with `jest.mock('../path/to/api')` on the top of the test file.

Comment: Yeah sorry its on the top. Just for the example here I put it there.

Comment: Then probably you should try to find out what is taking more than 5 seconds